# What is the value given to 'mcm'?

Tags: c

That's the solution to the "Write a program that calculates the minimum common multiple of two numbers in C" our proffesor posted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int n1, n2, mcm;
    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

    mcm = (n1 > n2) ? n1 : n2;

    while (1) {
        if (mcm % n1 == 0 && mcm % n2 == 0) {
            printf("The Minimum Common Multiple of %d and %d is %d.", n1, n2, mcm);
            break;
        }
        ++mcm;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the same code you can find on programiz but without including the conio.h library.
What is the purpose of using the whole line where mcm gets a value?
Does it have something to do with the conio.h library?
When i wrote the code myself i just stated mcm=1; and it worked just fine.

Comment: All of the code is very basic C code, and should be well explained by any decent beginners book. The only thing to note is that `<conio.h>` include... It's not needed. That header file is non-standard and is a left-over from the old DOS days. You should never need to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [Ternary Operator](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html). To quote:

> ```
> <condition> ? <true-case-code> : <false-case-code>;
> ```
>
> The ternary operator allows you to execute different code depending on
> the value of a condition, and the result of the expression is the
> result of the executed code.

---

> What is the purpose of using the whole line where `mcm` gets a value?

So your line of code:

```
mcm = (n1 > n2) ? n1 : n2;
```

It means:

```
if (n1 > n2)
    mcm = n1;
else
    mcm = n2;
```

Answer (score 2):

It saves some cpu cycles, since you know values less than the larger of the two inputs cannot be a common multiple of the two values, so there is no need to test those values.